# bundle exec rake doesn't work

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rake, bundler

I am using terminal on a macbook air and any command beginning with `bundle exec rake db:` does't work. I am trying to remove all the tables from my database (aka start from scratch) and them migrate once. Every time I execute any `bundle exec rake db:` command it just waits a few seconds then stops. Here is a `--trace` for `bundle exec rake db:rollback` as an example.

```
** Invoke db:rollback (first_time)
** Invoke db:environment (first_time)
** Execute db:environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:rollback
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke db:environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

Comment: Do you have the Bundler installed? `gem install bundler`.

Comment: Of course I do!!! It used to work, now it doesn't.

Comment: and bundle install, and all other bundler commands work